# how to select data from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

I have 4 tables, i am very confused to select the data.

I have this fields in my 4 tables

```
t1 -> student_id
  given_name
  user_name

t2 -> school_year
  sem
  class
  student_id
  main_id

t3 -> subject_id
  main_id

t4 -> subject_id
  subject_name
```

I need to select (given_name, subject_name, class & main_id). How?

I try like this

```
SELECT t2.school_year, t2.rp_main_sem, t2.rp_main_class,  t4.name, t4.subject_id, t1.given_name, t1.user_name FROM t1, t2, t3, t4 WHERE t2.school_year = 2011 AND t2.sem = 1 AND t2.class = 'ES3A' AND t3.subject_id = t4.subject_id AND t1.student_id = t2.rp_main_student_id
```

Comment: `SELECT t1.given_name, t4.subject_name, t2.class, t2.main_id FROM t1, t2, t4`

Comment: in t3 the primary key is main_id (or in t2)?

Comment: school_year = 2011 and sem = 1 (in where condition)

Comment: @apssiva: I added the `WHERE` clause to my query, but if you need to add something to your question, you must click on the `edit` button below your question to add the extra details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.given_name, t4.subject_name, t2.main_id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.main_id = t3.main_id
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t3.subject_id = t4.subject_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to JOIN the tables. Each table should have a PRIMARY (or UNIQUE) key, and references (so called FOREIGN KEYs) to the other tables.

```
SELECT given_name , t4.subject_name, t2.class, t3.main_id
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 
ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id
JOIN t3
ON t2.main_id = t3.main_id
JOIN t4
ON t2.subject_id = t3.subject_id
WHERE t2.school_year = "2011""  and t2.sem = 1 --added where because of your comment
```

So we assume that

- the students' table `t1` has PK `student_id`
- the subjects' table `t4` has PK `subject_id`
- `t2` is a associative table that links students (using their
  `student_id`) to classes, which have a `main_id`.
- `t3` is an associative table that links subjects to classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT
      t1.given_name,
      t3.subject_name,
      t2.class,
      t2.main_id 
   FROM
      t1 
   JOIN
      t2 
         ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id 
   JOIN
      t3 
         ON t2.main_id = t3.main_id 
   JOIN
      t4 
         ON t3.subject_id = t4.subject_ID
```

this should do it but please tell us in what form you need the data. do you want to get the classes per student? or students per class?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.given_name, t4.subject_name, t2.class, t2.main_id
  from t1 
  join t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id
  join t2.main_id = t3.main_id
  join t3.subject_id = t4.subject_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   SELECT t1.given_name, t4.subject_name, t2.class, t2.main_id
     FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id
LEFT JOIN t3
       ON t2.main_id = t3.main_id
LEFT JOIN t4
       ON t3.subject_id = t4.subject_id
    WHERE t2.school_year = 2011 
      AND t2.sem = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_name1.given_name,table_name4.subject_name,
table_name2.class,table_name2.main_id
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.studen_id=table_name2.studen_id
INNER JOIN table_name3
ON table_name2.main_id=table_name3.main_id
INNER JOIN table_name4
ON table_name3.subject_id=table_name4.subject_id
```